# Python - получить данные от медленного web-сервера?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, lazyloading, aiohttp

Собственно имеется: python3.8, веб-сервер (сайт с конкретным url).
Сайт очень медленно отдает данные - т.е. при запросе к url, на сайте некоторое время висит кастомная анимация загрузки примерно 5-15 сек. После чего отображается на странице пару таблиц с нужным содержимым (выглядит как простой html), есть некоторая форма для отправки данных на сайт (4 поля ввода текста и кнопка). Так же присутствует некоторый фрейм внутри которого можно скролить записи введенные через форму ранее.

Информации о том, на чем написан сайт не имею (и не факт что получу). Знаю что есть jQuery, и какие-то собственные js+php. Страничка раз в минуту обновляется самостоятельно.

Вопрос: мне необходимо с использованием python вытаскивать уже сгенерированную страничку со всем ее содержимым? requests и aiohttp уже пробовал и либо не правильно готовил, либо что-то не так.

Comment: Ссылку на сайт сможете дать?

Comment: Увы не могу - сайт используется исключительно в intranet

Comment: пример кода с реквестом покажете? в нем можно время прописать, какое будет реквест запрашивать страницу. если вам джаваскрипт нужно выполнить, то это, например, селениум сделает.

Comment: @JTProg Если сайт периодически обновляет данные, то попробуйте в браузере в инструментах разработчика посмотреть какие запросы и куда делает сайт. Вкладка Network -> XHR.

Comment: @Serhii вот так для примера: [https://pastebin.com/0RE4eEnX](https://pastebin.com/0RE4eEnX)

Comment: @Andrey, спасибо - забыл я что-то про этот раздел. ИМХО судя по тому что я вижу там обращение происходит к конкретному php, судя по названия подозреваю что там реализован Ajax.

Comment: @JTProg если после загрузки основной страницы, есть какой-то запрос к серверу для обновления данных, то это скорее всего будет видно в инструментах разработчика. `timeout=25` этот параметр отвечате за то, сколько времени ждать ответа от сервера. Как я понимаю, вы ответ получаете сразу, а уже после на странице выполняется какой-то Javascript? Если так,то наверное не поможет выставление таймаута.

Comment: попробуйте селениум и все. просто, верно, надежно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Расковыряв весь JS-код который грузился в страничке, я смог найти те самые endpoint'ы которые дергались с помощью JavaScript.

Так же удалось найти разработчика, который делал этот "сайт". Разработчик доделать не решился, но выдал конкретные параметры с которыми можно дергать endpoint'ы.

Вопрос можно считать закрытым.